# URL Field not appearing correctly in anchor

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I have run into a very interesting problem. I am working on a site for a client of mine and have run into this issue using Advanced Custom Fields no wordpress. I have added a new custom field to the site for their rewards program spot, and I am having trouble getting the url field to work corretly. I have the code added to the template php file that it needs to be in and it looks like this at the moment.

```
    <div class="row">
        <?php $ficvalue = get_field('free-icecream-url');
            if ($ficvalue) {
                $ficurl = esc_url($ficvalue);
            }?>
        <h3 class="heading" style="text-align: center;"><?php the_field('free-icecream-header'); ?></h3>
        <a href"<?php echo $ficurl; ?>" class="btn btn-primary" style="max-width: 15em;"><?php the_field('free-icecream-btn'); ?></a>
    </div>
```

When I put the url into the custom url field on the backend in the page editor, it doesn't appear in the anchor correctly. if I add this line to the page, it shows the url correctly on the page itself:

```
    <?php echo get_field('free-icecream-url'); ?>
```

This will show the url as it is inserted into the custom field, however adding it into the anchor's href like this provides a different result.

```
    <a href="<?php echo get_field('free-icecream-url'); ?>" class="btn btn-primary" style="max-width: 15em;"><?php the_field('free-icecream-btn'); ?></a>

    <!-- results as the following in chromes inspect -->
    <!-- https: www.rococoicecream.com rococo-rewards
         Instead of https://www.rococoicecream.com/rococorewards -->
```

I have tried to use esc_url() and esc_html() to no avail. and when using the_field() it yields the same results. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I thought ACF had to use underscores and not dashes in their custom-fields? `free-icecream-url` to `free_icecream_url` for example, in both ACF and your code. Please try?

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I had no idea about that. However the way I have it written actually works just fine. I was having an issue because I forgot to put the = after href.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question here was answered shortly after posting it. I updated the original question but I will also place it here. I found the problem I was having was that I missed a = after the href in the anchor for my button. After finding that out, it works like a charm.